# Catching exceptions in async code called synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, exception, asynchronous, asp.net-membership

I have thrift service for authentication. `catch (AccountNotFoundException)` doesn't catch the exception unless I call  it in Task.Run. The strange thing is that test case is fine. Why? Is it because task.start() is on the different level than catch?

```
    public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
    {
         var task = client.GetUserByEmail(email, false);
         return task.Result;
         // I changed to
         // return Task.Run(() => client.GetUserByEmail(email, false)).Result.UserName;
         // and I was able to catch the exception
    }

    public async Task<AccountDetails> GetAccountDetailsByEmail(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            return await Call(() => client.getAccountDetailsByEmail(email));
        }
        catch (AccountNotFoundException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private async Task<T> Call<T>(Func<T> call)
    {
        try
        {
            transport.Open();
            var thriftTask = new Task<T>(call);
            thriftTask.Start();
            return await thriftTask;
        }
        catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            transport.Close();
        }
    }
```

Test case works just fine

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Nonexisting_User_I_Expect_To_Be_Null()
    {
        var user = Provider.GetUser("idontexist@bar.com", false);
        Assert.IsNull(user);
    }
```

EDIT:

I have a following theory why my code run ok: The code was working because I was lucky. Request and async was handled by the same thread so it shared the same context so it didn't block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you *shouldn't* be calling asynchronous methods synchronously. As I describe on my blog, the [approach you're using is prone to deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The reason you're seeing an unexpected exception type is because `Result` will wrap any task exceptions in an `AggregateException`. To avoid this, you can call `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

This doesn't have anything to do with `Start`, but since you mention it, the `Start` member doesn't really have a use case. There's never a good reason to use it. Instead, use `Task.Run`:

```
var thriftTask = Task.Run(call);
```

Comment: Can you explain more why task.start is a bad idea? http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/

Comment: Also, the code is called in custom membership provider which implements abstract methods e.g. public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline) How to call it then when I can't change the interface to make async "all the way down"

Comment: @lukas: `Task.Start` is just unnecessary; `Task.Run` is shorter and clearer and avoids a problematic task state ([see my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html)). And the best solution is to change your custom membership provider so that it can have asynchronous implementations.

Comment: The problem is I need to override abstract class methods and I cannot change signature to async.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. What I'm saying is that the best approach is to change the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

See here for details of exception handling for async code. It may be that you're catching an AccountNotFoundException, when you really want to be catching an Exception, which will have an *InnerException* set to the AccountNotFoundException:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

An excerpt:

**The task's IsFaulted property is set to True, the task's Exception.InnerException property is set to the exception, and the exception is caught in the catch block.**

```
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        Task<string> theTask = DelayAsync();

        try
        {
            string result = await theTask;
            Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Task IsCanceled: " + theTask.IsCanceled);
        Debug.WriteLine("Task IsFaulted:  " + theTask.IsFaulted);
        if (theTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Task Exception Message: "
                + theTask.Exception.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine("Task Inner Exception Message: "
                + theTask.Exception.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> DelayAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        // Uncomment each of the following lines to 
        // demonstrate exception handling. 

        //throw new OperationCanceledException("canceled");
        //throw new Exception("Something happened.");
        return "Done";
    }
```